# How to stop adding values to a list with empty line

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add values to a list, and stop adding with empty line:

```
def main():
    signal = []
    i = 0
    print("Enter the data points of the signal. Stop with empty line.\n")


    while i != "":
        value = float(input())
        signal.append(value)
        i += 1
    print(signal)


main()
```

However, when I press enter (empty line) I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Omistaja\Downloads\template_median_filter.py", line 30, in main
    value = float(input())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

How to proceed?

Comment: at no point `i` (an integer) will be equal to an empty string. You need to revise the logic

Comment: Ask yourself, when would `while i != ""` **ever happen**? You initialize `i = 0`, you then, in the loop, increment it `i += 1`, it will *always* be a (monotonically increasing) integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
def main():
    signal = []
    i = 0
    print("Enter the data points of the signal. Stop with empty line.\n")

    while True:
        i += 1
        data = input("Data point {}: ".format(i))
        if data == "":
            break
        signal.append(float(data))
    print("\nThe signal is: {}".format(signal))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a counter. Just check if the input is empty

```
signal = []
while True:
    points = input("Enter a data point for the signal. Stop with empty line.\n")
    if not points:
        break
    signal.append(float(points))
print(signal)
```